# using as a syntactic convenience for Dispose on a Stream

Tags: c#, dispose, using-statement

I'm a little confused. I've been spending time looking into a variety of topics to ensure my code is robust, including `IDisposable` and its very own syntactic sugar of the `using` statement to ensure unmanaged resources are released.

As I understand it, `using` is translated by the compiler into a `try-finally` block with the object in the `try` block and the call to `Dispose` in the `finally` block.

---

As per my understanding, this would make the following two pieces of my code functionally equivalent -

**using**

```
public void LoadFile(string filePath)
{
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter(); 

    if (File.Exists(filePath)) 
    { 
        using (Stream input = File.OpenRead(filePath))
        { 
            // ... 
        }
    } 
}
```

**Dispose**

```
public void LoadFile(string filePath)
{
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter(); 

    if (File.Exists(filePath)) 
    { 
        try
        {
            Stream input = File.OpenRead(filePath);
        }
        finally 
        {
            input.Dispose(); 
        }
    } 
}
```

---

This is where I'm confused. In the first example, using `using`, I'm not sure how I can put in my own exception handler when it is structured this way, as the underlying `try-finally` is obfuscated.

In the second example, using `Dispose`, I get the compiler error "The name input does not exist in this context".

Obviously I'm not understanding this fully... Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Please check the [documentation for the using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) on MSDN to find the actual code this is equivalent to.

Comment: D'oh. Thank you. I actually had that page open in front of me for reference and somehow misread it... *facepalm*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `using` doesn't prevent you from adding whatever exception handling you need:

```
public void LoadFile(string filePath)
{
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter(); 

    if (File.Exists(filePath)) 
    { 
        using (Stream input = File.OpenRead(filePath))
        { 
            try
            {
                // Whatever
            }

            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                // Do something with exception -
                // could log and suppress, or rethrow,
                // or whatever you need.
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

or

```
public void LoadFile(string filePath)
{
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter(); 

    if (File.Exists(filePath)) 
    { 
        try
        {
            using (Stream input = File.OpenRead(filePath))
            { 
                // Whatever
            }
        }

        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            // Do something with exception -
            // could log and suppress, or rethrow,
            // or whatever you need.
        }
    } 
}
```

It just ensures that no matter what*, the file will be closed.

*barring something nasty like `Environment.FailFast()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your variable outside of the `try` block so it will be accessible from catch and finally blocks:

```
if (File.Exists(filePath)) 
{ 
    Stream input = null;
    try
    {
       input = File.OpenRead(filePath);
    }
    finally 
    {
        if(input != null)
           input.Dispose(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Better yet, `Stream input = File.OpenRead(filePath);` before the `try`, both for simplicity and to match the behaviour of `using`.

Comment: @hvd But then if there is an exception thrown by `OpenRead` it won't be within the `try-catch-finally` block so won't be handled? Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @Eilidh Yes, that's correct. But if `OpenRead` throws an exception, `input` won't have been assigned a value, so there's nothing to call `Dispose()` on anyway.

Comment: @hvd Sure. But then the exception is unhandled?

Comment: @Eilidh Indeed. And if it's inside the `try`...`finally`, it's also unhandled unless there's a handler somewhere up the call stack, so there's no difference.

Comment: @Eilidh Unhandled in that method, yes - but it could be handled in one of the calling methods.

Comment: @Eilidh Remember, `try { try { throw new Exception(); } finally { /* ignore */ } } catch { Console.WriteLine("caught!"); }` will print "caught!". `finally` doesn't swallow exceptions.

Comment: @MatthewWatson So should my code be `try { using (Stream input = File.OpenRead(filePath) { } } catch (Exception e) { }` in order to catch any potential exceptions with `OpenRead`?

Comment: @Eilidh In most cases, you shouldn't be catching such exceptions unless you know how to handle them. Leave it for the caller to decide what to do with the exception, just make sure to clean up after yourself before passing the exception on.

Comment: @Eilidh Yes, if you know how to handle it at that point. Otherwise, what hvd said.